# Как сделать проверку, через sender_chat?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

[image: Командная строка]Подскажите, как сделать проверку, является ли отправитель сообщения администратором группы. Использую библиотеку PyTelegramBotApi.

Нашел в документации, как теперь из всего этого ,сделать код проверки.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember

Весь код

```py
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.entities is not None and message.chat.id)
def delete_links(message):
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
            if message.sender_chat and message.sender_chat == "supergroup":
                return bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
            else:
                return
```

Comment: Покажите свой обработчик сообщения

Comment: @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.entities is not None and message.chat.id)
def delete_links(message):
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
         if message.sender_chat and message.sender_chat == "supergroup":
          return
         bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        else:
            return

Answer (score 0):

Непонятна Ваша конкретная задача, но получить данные пользователя чата можно с помощью метода [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember). Примерно в Вашем случае это должно выглядеть так.

```py
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.entities is not None and message.chat.id)
def delete_links(message):
    if message.chat.type != "supergroup":
        return 
    
    member = bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id)

    if isinstance(member, types.ChatMemberMember):
        for entity in message.entities:
            if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
                return bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Описание:

1. Отправлено ли сообщение в группе
2. Если да, проверяет права пользователя в чате, является ли он администратором
3. Если нет, проходит по сообщению, если в нём есть ссылки, **удаляет сообщение**.

Comment: Админ теперь может размещать ссылку, но и пользователи теперь могут.Нужно чтобы ссылка пользователя исчезала,ну и соответственно админ мог размещать.

Comment: Код запускает и работает, но с ошибкой
SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
if message.chat.type is not "supergroup":

Может и за этого, пользователь может отправлять ссылку.

Comment: Ругается, на эту строку:
    if message.chat.type is not "supergroup":

Comment: Обновил ответ, проверьте

Comment: А Теперь у Админа исчезает ссылка и  у пользователя, а надо чтобы только, у пользователя исчезала ссылка.
Ошибка исчезла, но все равно, лучше не стало.

Comment: Сейчас проверьте

Comment: Тоже самое, все могут размещать ссылку, надо чтобы только админ.

Comment: Почему-то мне кажется, что Вы код неправильно скопировали